# Why do verbs need to be pluralised when you are using a name at the beginning, but not when you use 'You' at the beginning?

Tags: grammar

Examples:

'You like cake.'
and
'Lucas likes cake.'

'You run fast.'
and
'John runs fast.'

Why are the verbs pluralised when the name is used? Thanks!

Comment: Who said the verb is being pluralized?

Comment: Do you mean: Why are verbs conjugated and why do conjugations differ based on person?

Comment: I run, you run, he runs.  I am, you are, he is.  First, second, and third person singular.  We run, you run, they run.  We are, you are, they are.  First, second, and third person plural.

Answer (score 2):

The s, on the end of the verb is not the form of plural, as it would be for nouns (e.g. book**s**). It is the standard verb conjugation stating that when in present tense, third person, singular, you need to add an s to the end of the verb.

Example:

```
I run
You run
He/she/it runs <- only need to change here
We run
You run
They run
```